# Criando método em C# ,onde os parametros contém?

Tags: c#, orientação-a-objetos

Para que serve, adicionar "?" a frente da variável de parâmetro?
Exemplo:

```
public void somar(int n1, Date data?){

}
```

OU

```
public void somar(int n1, Date? data){

}
```

Comment: O segundo exemplo é para dizer que aquele parâmetro é nullable. Ou seja, um int, naturalmente, não pode receber `null`, apenas um número, com já `int?` pode receber nulo. Agora eu nunca vi o primeiro exemplo.

Comment: Isto não está relacionado ao parâmetro e sim ao tipo.

Comment: Obrigado, pessoal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Está interrogação permite que o campo receba um valor nulo. Por exemplo quando declaramos algo assim:

```
int i;
```

Por padrão ele receberá o valor zero, ja quando declaramos:

```
int? i;
```

Ele recebe por padrão o valor null.

**Tipos Anuláveis**

Os tipos que permitem valor nulo podem representar todos os valores de um tipo subjacente e um valor adicional null.

Fonte: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/using-nullable-types